# How to know which line in Javascript code caused an XHR request?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, opera

I have a very large AngularJS based app and I am trying to find the line of code that causes an XHR request. I created an XHR breakpoint in Opera and it got hit but the Call Stack shows only one line in an Ajax.ts file and this information is not useful enough.

Is there a way to easily find the line of code outside of Angularjs and vendor scripts which caused an Ajax call? How to show more lines in the Call Stack?
(the same xhr breakpoint doesn't work in Chrome but works in Opera)

[image]

Comment: Do you have a URL where I can reproduce? You can submit it privately via this form: [Submit a URL to the Chrome DevTools team](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSef3LpF0JcwQLCUABaQAdNFItKEQcVosRCrLltk930DRUC1kA/viewform).

Comment: Did you try hovering on Initiator in network panel? It lists entire call stack.

Comment: @Kayce Basques Sorry it's an internal app